# javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Data must start with zero

Tags: java, security, rsa, encryption

First of all, this is not a duplicate question. I am facing a very strange issue.

Following is what I do.

**Case 1:**

1. Generate Key Pair
2. Encrypt Using Private Key
3. Decrypt Using Public Key

Everything works fine.

**Case 2:**

1. Load Certificate from Mozila Firefox Key Store
2. Use Certificate A
3. Encrypt Using Private Key of Certificate A
4. Decrypt Using Public Keu of Certificate A

Everything works fine.

**Case 3:**

1. Load Certificate from Internet Explorer Key Store
2. Use Certificate A
3. Encrypt Using Private Key of Certificate A
4. Decrypt Using Public Keu of Certificate A

At Decrypt time, I get error of BadPadding exception

Following is snippet of each of my codes.

**Generating Key Pair**

```
    KeyPair keyPair = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA").generateKeyPair(); 
    PublicKey publicKey = keyPair.getPublic();
    PrivateKey privateKey = keyPair.getPrivate();
```

**Load Mozilla KeyStore**

```
    String strCfg = System.getProperty("user.home")+ File.separator + "jdk6-nss-mozilla.cfg";
    Provider p1 = new sun.security.pkcs11.SunPKCS11(strCfg);
    Security.addProvider(p1);
    keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS11");
    keyStore.load(null, "password".toCharArray());
```

**Content of Config file**

```
name=NSS
slot=2
library=C:/Program Files/Mozilla Firefox/softokn3.dll
nssArgs="configDir='C:/Documents and Settings/pratik.vohera.DIGI-CORP/Application Data/Mozilla/Firefox/Profiles/t48xsipj.default' certPrefix='' keyPrefix=''     secmod='secmod.db' flags=readOnly"
```

**Load IE KeyStore**

```
    keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("Windows-MY");
    keyStore.load(null, null);
```

**Get Public and Private key from KeyStore**

```
    if (keyStore != null) {
    Enumeration<String> enumaration = null;
    try {
        enumaration = keyStore.aliases();
    } catch (KeyStoreException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    ArrayList<String> certiList;
    while (enumaration.hasMoreElements()) {
        String aliases = enumaration.nextElement();
        certiList = new ArrayList<String>();
        certiList.add(aliases);
        try {
            selectedCert = keyStore.getCertificate(aliases);
            selectedpublickey = (RSAPublicKey) selectedCert.getPublicKey();
            selectedAlias = aliases;
            selectedprivateKey = (PrivateKey) keyStore.getKey(selectedAlias, null);}
        } catch (KeyStoreException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

**Encryption**

```
private static String publicEncrypt(String text, Key pubKey) throws Exception {
    BASE64Encoder bASE64Encoder = new BASE64Encoder();
    byte[] plainText = text.getBytes();
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding");
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, pubKey);
String encryptedText = bASE64Encoder.encode(cipher.doFinal(plainText));
return encryptedText;
}
```

**Decryption**

```
private static String privateDecrypt(String text, Key priKey)throws Exception     {
    BASE64Decoder base64Decoder = new BASE64Decoder();
byte[] encryptText = base64Decoder.decodeBuffer(text);
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding");
cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, priKey);
String decryptedString = new String(cipher.doFinal(encryptText));
return decryptedString;
}
```

**Exception Stacktrace**

```
javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Data must start with zero
at sun.security.rsa.RSAPadding.unpadV15(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.rsa.RSAPadding.unpad(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.crypto.provider.RSACipher.a(DashoA13*..)
at com.sun.crypto.provider.RSACipher.engineDoFinal(DashoA13*..)
at javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(DashoA13*..)
at test.testclass.privateDecrypt(testclass.java:198)
at test.testclass.test(testclass.java:137)
at test.testclass.main(testclass.java:120)
```

I have been working on this for a long time. This is very important. Do let me know if any further information is required.

Comment: You don't encrypt with a privat key. You encrypt a message with someone's public key and they decrypt it with their private key. That way the privat key stays private. YOu can sign messages with a private key, but thats different and not what your code appears to be doing. What are you trying to do ? Finally, in case 3 it looks you you say your using one certificate to encrypt and another to decrypt. Is this accurate and if so why ?

Comment: Can you give us an example of what the output from your encryption function looks like?

Comment: Almost certainly you're not using public/private keys that are part of the same pair.

Comment: @imichaelmiers I am using private key encryption to sign the data. In my application we have a requirement where we have to match signs at the time of tender opening for that purpose we require. Secondly, in case 3 I am using same certificate's  private key for encryption and public key decryption. If I would have been using different certificates than I should have failed in case 1 and 2.

Comment: @KeithRandall, I am using public/private keys that are part of the same pair and that is why it is working in case 1 and case 2.

Comment: @KuntalShah : you get badding exception when the key used to decrypt is not the right one being used.

Comment: @JonBright 
Plain String
Hello 
Encrypted String
ØàC!î¿@¬!=∑åßmü˙–5Â≈£¯‘1Ø‘é(£ ;±m0e\≈˝
·∆€ÂÚó≠1ΩËAJjí⁄µ∑º¬Ó∞[öL=3ΩZÁÃv~œàÁc†≤—í‰ùI‹√Æº£_ˆÖ†NŒBx!`≤;ß8™π Tsp¥,ç

Comment: @Ashwin I am using proper keys as same key pairs work properly in other 2 cases.

Comment: @KuntalShah : Convert the encrypted form into it into base 64 first and then when feeding to the decryption algorithm, use base64decoder to feed in the original bytes. please tell the result.

Comment: @Ashwin the base64 encoding gives same result works in first two case and in third case it gives the same error.

Answer (score 1):

In the third case, the problem is: You try to encrypt using the private key and decrypt using the public key which is wrong. You should always decrypt using the private key.